# Why did Tiger Lily lie to Peter?

Tags: peter-pan, pan-2015

Why did Tiger Lily lie to Peter about his mother? I know she claimed it was to keep him on his destined path but surely if it's his destiny he will end up doing what he was meant to anyway. If it was me and I found out she lied I would tell her where to stick it.

Comment: *"...surely if it's his destiny he will end up doing what he was meant to anyway."* Depends on the definition of "destiny" used in the story.  In some stories, destiny is an unavoidable force that will get you no matter how hard you try to avoid it (or sometimes *because you tried to avoid it.*)  In other stories, it's more of a prediction or prophecy, that may or may not come true depending on the decisions of the named parties.  It would seem that Tiger Lily, at least, believed in the latter definition.

Comment: Which version of the story is this? Film? Book? Video game?

Comment: The version i was referring to is the 2015 Pan, Isnt prediction and prophecy more of a belief, like Tiger Lily has done this for her own means and ends.